# Clarification of js checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure something with the JS (which is not my strong suit). I have setup a fiddle which can be seen here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TL6QP/)

Here's the code I am using:

```
function find_select(){
if (document.getElementById("nsp").selected == true)
{
    document.getElementById('nsp_form').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('feedback_form').style.display = 'none';
}
else if (document.getElementById("feedback").selected == true)
{
    document.getElementById('nsp_form').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('feedback_form').style.display = 'block';
}
else if (document.getElementById("pre_alerts_yes").selected == true)
{
    document.getElementById('nsp_form').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('pre_alerts_yes').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('feedback_form').style.display = 'none';
}   

else{
    document.getElementById('nsp_form').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('feedback_form').style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

What I would like to have happen is when someone selects the "Send Pre-Alerts" option, for it to then open up just one more drop down box, which displays the types for the send pre-alerts options. But I failed at getting it to do so, specifically at the:

```
if (document.getElementById("pre_alerts_yes").selected == true)
```

So does that need to check if the nsp box is open as well, because the pre_alerts_yes only shows if the nsp box is opened and selected for true. Sorry for the lengthy write up, but it's needed to understand it.

Basically a chain select method going on, with 3 levels of drops that could occur. Maybe a fresh set of eyes could tell me what I am doing wrong, as the final "pre_alerts_yes" doesn't expand the final box.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open `pre_alerts_yes` you have to show `nsp_form` first because `pre_alerts_yes` os under the `nsp_form div` which is `display:none;` first make it `display:block;`

Comment: That's what is throwing me off. I do actually open the block first. If you look at the third section of code in the js section of jsfiddle you will see that I open the nsp block first then the pre_alerts_yes_form

Answer (score 0):

Just try to name different of ids and use jquery use something like that

```
    <label for="input_title">Phone Type:</label>
<select name="phone_type" id="select_form" class="input-block-level" >
    <option id="blank" value="blank"></option>
    <option id="blank" value="house">House Phone</option>
    <option id="nsp" value="cellphone">Normal Cell (Non Smart Phone)</option>
    <option id="feedback" value="smartphone">SmartPhone</option>
</select>
<div id="nsp_form" style="display: none;">
    <label for="input_title">Send Pre-Alerts:</label>
    <select name="pre_alerts" id="pre_alerts_yes_open" class="input-block-level" >
        <option id="blank" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="pre_alerts_yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="normal_cell">No</option>
    </select>

    <div id="pre_alerts_yes_form" style="display: none;">
        <label for="input_title">Pre-Alerts Type:</label>
        <select name="pre_alerts" id="pre_alerts_from" class="input-block-level" >
            <option value="pre_alerts_yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="normal_cell">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <label for="input_title">Alert Type:</label>
    <select name="cell_type" class="input-block-level">
        <option value="house">SMS Message (Standard)</option>
        <option value="normal_cell">SMS Message (Customized)</option>
        <option value="smart_phone">Phone Call (Standard Voice)</option>
        <option value="smart_phone">Phone Call (Customized Voice)</option>
        <option value="smart_phone">Phone Call (Audio Call)</option>
        <option value="smart_phone">Phone Call (Audio Prompt Call)</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="feedback_form" style="display: none;">feedback</div>
```

and jquery like that

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#select_form').on('change',function()
    {
        if ( $(this).val() == 'cellphone' ) {
            $('#nsp_form').show();
            $('#feedback_form').hide();
        } else if ( $(this).val() == 'smartphone' ) {
            $('#nsp_form').hide();
            $('#feedback_form').show();
        } else {
            $('#nsp_form').hide();
            $('#feedback_form').hide();         
        } 
    });

    $('#pre_alerts_yes_open').on('change',function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == 'pre_alerts_yes') {
            $('#nsp_form').show();
            $('#feedback_form').hide();
            $('#pre_alerts_yes_form').show();
        } else {
            $('#nsp_form').hide();
            $('#feedback_form').hide(); 
        }
    });
  <script>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I was closer with my example than what you provided. Thanks tho